# How to Disable Save, SaveAs button in MS-Word 2010/2013 using VBA

Tags: vba

Using VBA, I want to disable (or hide) the Save and SaveAs button shown in the File menu in MS Word 2013 so that the user cannot click them.

I have tried disabling these buttons using this:

```
Word.CommandBars("File").Controls("&Save").Enabled = False
Word.CommandBars("File").Controls("&Save").Visible = False
```

But this has no effect. Is there any way I can disable these buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 2007 the "menu controls" are no longer controlled via the CommandBars object model.So, to control menu items I have to define Ribbon XML that has to be either incorporated into the document, or be loaded as part of an Add-in.

To disable Save and SaveAs in Word 2010 I used this XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="FileSave" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsMenu" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsWordDocx" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsWordDotx" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAs" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsWord97_2003" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsPdfOrXps" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsOtherFormats" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveToDocumentManagementServer" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="SaveSelectionToQuickPartGallery" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FrameSaveCurrentAs" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSaveAsWordOpenDocumentText" enabled="false" />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

I used [Custom UI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx) for executing and testing this code. This [link](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html) provides a nice training of how to use Custom UI Editor.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I am trying this. But are you sure that this will disable the Save button as well.

Comment: @rsKRISH It will not disable save button. But when you click on save button the workbook would not be saved.

Comment: Ok Thanks Santosh.
But is there any way I can disable Save button also.?

Comment: @rsKRISH I believe this is better way.

Comment: Yes no doubt this is a better way , but I require to disable the buttons also.

Comment: @rsKRISH if you get the solution which you are looking for please post it as answer.