# Prevent "Save" in Word (Save As is okay)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm just wondering how to prevent (stop) a user from saving a document (just "Save", "Save As" is okay).  I have a .docm that I'm using as a template, where the user just fills in three fields.  I don't want them to accidentally fill it in, then save over the template.

I've seen a [few SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977599/how-to-disable-save-saveas-button-in-ms-word-2010-2013-using-vba) that give code, but when I put the following in "ThisDocument" under "Microsoft Word Objects", nothing happens when I hit save:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("Please 'Save As' instead.")
    Debug.Print "Someone tried to save."
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I'm expecting when I hit the save icon (or CTRL+S) the messagebox to pop up.  ..that doesn't happen (nor does the `debug.print` line work).  What am I overlooking?

Related question: Should I just forget doing the above, and just create a true template document (.dotm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your users should be creating new documents from a template. Save the template in the users' Templates folder so that they can access it via File/New when they want to create a new document...

Concerning the code you show: Workbook is for Excel and won't trigger in Word. In Word the event is Document_BeforeSave and you'd want to set the SaveAsUI parameter to True to force the dialog box to show.

Comment: "Workbook is for Excel...", d'oh! I don't know how I didn't realize that. Thanks for the advice!